# Access Windows 10 & create new local user account, not knowing old passwords nor admin

Tags: windows-10

I joined a new lab, there is a win10 machine here that used to belong to old users with whom I don't have contact. No-one here knows the admin password too.

When I turn on the computer, it immediately wants me to put in the password of one of the old users.

Instead, I want to go around it - and set up my new local account.

Hw do I do that though? Right now, it seems that I cannot start the system - so cannot use the computer.

Comment: Do a restart and upon restart, repeatedly press F8 to attempt to get into safe mode.

Comment: Ok, I see: "Windows Boot manager" twice, still no safe mode option

Comment: You may have just reinstall Windows if the people who see it up prevent all non-regular access.

Comment: okay, thank you both! John & Moab, I will read all the solutions and report what/if it worked .